# Task Registered in Application_Start Storing Results from Referenced Repository

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a task that is executed during Application_Start in my application named **RegisterRuleTextResolverTask**

```
public class RegisterRuleTextResolverTask : Disposable, ITask
{
    private readonly RuleRepository _ruleRepository;

    private readonly IRuleTextResolver _ruleTextResolver;

    public RegisterRuleTextResolverTask(IRuleTextResolver ruleTextResolver, RuleRepository ruleRepository)
    {
        Guard.IsNotNull(ruleTextResolver);
        Guard.IsNotNull(ruleRepository);
        _ruleTextResolver = ruleTextResolver;
        _ruleRepository = ruleRepository;
    }

    #region ITask Members

    public void Execute()
    {
        _ruleTextResolver.Resolver = _ruleRepository.GetRuleByName;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In this task, a global Resolver for the **IRuleTextResolver** instance is set to a method named **GetRuleByName** which accepts a string and returns a rule string in the **RuleRepository** class.

```
public class RuleRepository
{
    private readonly EmployeeToolkitDbContext _database;

    public RuleRepository(EmployeeToolkitDbContext database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public string GetRuleByName(string name)
    {
        var rule = _database.Rules.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(name));

        return rule?.Text;
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is the unexpected behavior that the result of **GetRuleByName** is being stored in IIS/IIS Express cache after the initial lookup for a rule, e.g. "AuthorizedUsers".

As administrative users will have access to modify these rules in the DB via a UI, this behavior is not desired.

My question is to ask if there is any way to avoid the caching of these values while keeping this tasks execution in the **Application_Start**. I want to avoid the overhead of executing this task in **BeginRequest** as it would add a lot of unnecessary overhead.